# Captcha run amok

Tags: bug

I just answered two questions on the main site, and I had to enter a captcha after each one.  This previously happened only once in a great while, so twice in a row is a radical change to the algorithm.  And yes, I was duly logged in.

Having captcha pop up when properly logged in is annoying enough (after all, I've already given a password), but every time after posting a answer is way out of line.

I don't want to make it three times in a row, and certainly don't want to put up with this crap every time.  Someone please let me know when this is fixed.  I'll probably still check in for responses in the mean time.

Comment: Argh!  It make me do a captcha to post this question.  I strongly resent being treated like a criminal even after proving who I am by loggin in.  Screw this.  I'm outta here until this is fixed.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting in your answer, or are you typing it in the editor?

Comment: @W5VO: In all three cases I just typed directly into the editor.

Comment: From what I gather some of these things are triggered by IP address, I just about always use a static IP so never get the captcha but gather it can sometimes occur with a dynamic IP because by chance you end up with the same IP address that someone had recently used to post a lot of spam/crap on the SE network. If you're using a dynamic IP might be worth just trying a router reboot so you (probably) get a new one.

Comment: @Peter: This was all from a single machine at work on the LAN.  Our network interfaces to the outside world via one static IP address.

Comment: The static IP is 74.93.16.125 in case that is of any help.

Comment: Are you still using an ancient browser?

Comment: Are you still experiencing a [plethora](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mTUmczVdik) of captchas?

Comment: @Jarrod: No, this problem seems to be gone now.  I stopped posting for a few days, then tried again by adding another answer here.  That didn't require a captcha and I haven't had to enter one since.  I guess somebody fixed something, but didn't tell us here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a problem with the bot-detecting bot (:$). Have you tried to log out and back in?

I'm trying to get help on the issue.

Comment: I tried logging out and logging back in, and it still made me enter a captcha when I posted the test answer to this question.  See my "answer" to this question.

Answer (score -1):

This is a test after logging out and logging back in again.  I won't know if it made me enter a captcha until I submit this, so I'll come back and edit this answer with the result.

Yes, it made me enter a captcha to post this.  It will probably do it again after this edit.

Comment: Actually, I didn't have to enter a captcha for the edit, only for the original post of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is another test to see if the captcha is still required.

No, this time it wasn't.  Nobody posted anything here, but maybe this has been fixed?